# GeoServer GWC blob store metatdata.properties file

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

We are currently running four GeoServer v23.2.1 instances with a shared embedded GeoWebCache.
The metadata.properties file is filled with \u0000 characters and log entries are showing:

> ERROR [memory.MemoryBlobStore] - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

We occasionally get out of memory with one or all instances where a reboot is needed.
It could be related to this question but a standalone GeoWebCache is not an option for us [GeoServer Cluster - Malformed \uxxxx encoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375754/geoserver-cluster-malformed-uxxxx-encoding)

Is there a way to force GeoServer to regenerate the gwc metadata.properties file?